# Ignore fields during deserialization in spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to ignore some fields during deserialization of json data in spring. I cannot use @JsonIgnore as the same model will be used in different methods and different fields need to be ignored.
I have tried to explain the situation with the below example.

```
class User
{
private String name;
private Integer id;
//getters and setters
}
```

This is the User class that will be used as model.

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/path1', method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> loadUser1(@RequestBody User user){
    System.out.println(user.name);
    //user.id is not required here
}
```

This is the first method that will use user.name and ignore user.id.

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/path2', method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> loadUser2(@RequestBody User user){
    System.out.println(user.id);
    //user.name is not required here
}
```

This is the second method that will use user.id and ignore user.name.

Comment: you can reate 2 response classes for that, one with "user.name" and other with "user.id"

Comment: Yes, that will be my last resort. But, is there any other way to do it? @Keaz

Comment: I dont think you can achieve without creating 2 response classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonFilter` to achieve dynamic filtering.

First, create a filter using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` and pass it to a filter provider `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider`.

Then, declare this filter on your bean using `@JsonFilter`.

In your case, this will do it:

```
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    // Getters and setters
}
```

This will apply the filter on your POJO:

```
public MappingJacksonValue getFiltered() {
    SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
    filterProvider.addFilter("myFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("id"));
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(1);
    user.setName("Me");
    MappingJacksonValue jacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(user);
    jacksonValue.setFilters(filterProvider);
    return jacksonValue;
}
```

Edit:
`SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` has factory methods to tender to almost all practical filtering scenarios. Use them appropriately.

Comment: I tried this method but it was unable to filter fields. After setting filter to jacksonValue I did this: User user2 = jacksonValue.getValue();. But user2 object still had both "id" and "name".

Comment: I misunderstood your question. The example works in case of _serialization_. If you were to return the user object to client, the filter would exclude fields according to your definition.

I don't understand why you would want to ignore fields during _**deserialization**_.

Comment: When I Tested my code through Fortify tool it said that it is a security risk. If your class has more variables than being sent by the user then a attacker may use this to set the extra variables too. security error category is cross site scripting: persistent.